# RSAT on Windows 10 fails to add node to server 2016 cluster

Tags: clustering, windows-10, windows-server

I have been testing server 2016 failover clustering. I have 3 hyper-v VMs running server 2016 core. I installed the RSAT tools on Windows 10 Pro to use the failover clustering wizard. I cannot add a node to the 2016 cluster using the Win10 machine, getting an error about the operating systems being different. When I go to a server 2016 machine with desktop experience, I can use the same wizard to successfully add the node. I assume it is because the OSs are the same.

My question is...is it true that a Windows 10 Pro machine will not be able to administer a server 2016 cluster?

Comment: Did you install the Technical Preview RSAT from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520?

Comment: Yes, the x64 file. The full filename is WindowsTH-RSAT_TP5_Update-x64.msu.

Comment: Have you tried with the updated RSAT Microsoft released on October 12? It would be from the same link as before but the download has new name, such as WindowsTH-RSAT_WS2016-x64.msu.

Comment: I will have to give it a try. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Suddenly had a chance to test, and was able to use the WS2016 version successfully to evict and re-add a node to the cluster. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RSAT tool was updated with the general availability of Windows Server 2016. By going to the same link as the preview RSAT, https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520, you can update your workstation with the new version.